# Python 3 in ROS indigo

Tags: ros, python3, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a script in python 3, it reads data from a serial port, do some processing and return some integer and float values. This script manipulates bytes in a way that it will be time consuming for me to adapt it to python2. Is there a way to run python3 script in ROS Indigo? I dont use any ros package in python, only external libraries like pyserial.

I try to install python3-pkg, but the package remove many(if not all) of my ros packages and do not install any substitutes.

Thanks,

Iuro Nascimento

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209417/python-3-in-ros-indigo/) by [gagarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22465/gagarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why the apt installation of rospkg removes existing packages, but the same happened to me. What works, actually, is to create a virtual machine with python3 interpreter ([virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), for example) and under it run *pip install rospkg*).

(additionally, you'd have to run *pip install catkin_pkg*, in order to run python3 scripts. I can confirm this approach works for basic ROS functionality - establishing nodes, publishing and subscribing to topics etc.However, there are packages that don't work with python3. In order to combine both - scripts that have to use python3 and those that have to use python2, I define in the shebang the interpreter to use, e.g. *#!/home/bot/virtualEnvs/v3/bin*)

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-20**:
The problem is that many ROS Python packages install different versions under the same file name, so the `python3-foo-bar` package has to "Conflict" with the corresponding `python-foo-bar`.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2020-01-12**:
I followed these steps but couldn't make it work. I posted my question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/341532/python-3-in-ros-indigo-on-raspberry-pi/). Could you please write down these steps from the beginning? Do I just need to run these two commands `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 myenv` and under `myenv` run `pip install rospkg`?